# Is it possible debug iOS Chrome on Windows 10?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

As the title says, I need to debug a website opened with mobile Chrome on an iOS device (iPod, iPad etc.) on Windows 10. I have successfully set up iOS Safari debugging on Windows 10 via Chrome DevTools ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter) , [helpful comment](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/79#issuecomment-351472710)). I would love to do the same thing except with Chrome or Firefox and not Safari. Is it even possible?

Comment: On what IOS version have you succefully set up IOS-Safari-Chrome debugging?

Comment: @BenCarp I think it was some 11 version but I don't know for sure - don't have the devices with me now and can't find it on my PC, sorry

Comment: You can try inspect https://inspect.dev it's not free but has 14 day trial so you can get things done within or can buy this.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it is. You'll need node first and (web inspector enabled on iOS>Settings>Safari) then...

1. Install weinre `sudo npm -g i weinre` (or) `npm i -g weinre`
2. Run weinre `weinre --boundHost YOUR_IP:PORT`
3. When it runs copy paste the following script to your code

`<script src="http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:PORT/target/target-script-min.js"></script>`

4. Connect your iOS device via USB
5. Go to `http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:PORT/client/` from your browser (your pc) where you want to debug and you'll see your device.

*Error in Step 2*

If you see any error in step 2, first check your IP via `ipconfig` and then bind a similar IP with a free port that is not being used. For example my local ip is 192.168.1.5 so I used the same with a free port - `192.168.1.5:4576`

*Error in Step 5*

If you can't see your device try adding a name `myDevice` to the script in **Step 3** as follows

`<script src="http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:PORT/target/target-script-min.js#myDevice"></script>`

Then in Step 5, when reaching your device add the device name to the URL as
`http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:PORT/client/#myDevice`

*SUCCESS*

If everything runs fine, you'll be able to inspect your code, read indexedDB, session and localStorage and see outputs in Console among other dev tools.

Comment: I'm impressed of how this worked so easily for me. Just had one problem: I was getting "weinre: unable to resolve boundHost address" when running the boundHost command, and had to change to "-all-" instead of my local IP address, and it succesfuly created a server at :8080

Comment: @zeion I'm not sure if it'll work that way because the ```target-script``` needs to be inserted in the code.

Comment: If you don't have access to the code, weinre gives you a script you can type in the url, injecting the script in the running website. For instance: `javascript:(function(e){e.setAttribute("src","http://localhost:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous");document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(e);})(document.createElement("script"));void(0);`

Comment: I tried running "weinre --boundHost <ip>:<port>" but kept getting the error "weinre: unable to resolve boundHost address:<ip>:<port>". The solution was to change the arguments to: "weinre --boundHost <ip> --httpPort <port>"

Comment: is it possible to simulate the iOS system (virtual machine)??

Answer (score 5):

I found this link very helpful.

No other answer or article on web is more straight forward than this: [washamdev](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/)

It's a verbose article so I cannot put everything here. Hope the link does not break.